# Dynamic Number of ItemWriters in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am currently working on a requirement like in ItemReader, for each record we will get a string containing comma separated values eg : "ABC,DEF,GHI" or "ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL" and we need to parse that string into separate tokens and write it to the new row in a table.

In first case records will be:

> row1 : key1, ABC
>
> row2 : key1, DEF
>
> row3 : key1, GHI

In second case, records will be:

> row1 : key1, ABC
>
> row2 : key1, DEF
>
> row3 : key1, GHI
>
> row4 : key1, JKL

So, in this requirement, we need to write the records dynamically depends upon the number of tokens in the String. Can we use compositeItemWriter here?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to, but that's not the approach I'd recommend.  If I understand your requirement correctly, you have an `ItemReader` reading n fields that are comma delimited and each of the *fields* within that record will end up as a new record in a database table.

If the above is correct, I'd recommend using an `ItemProcessor` to break down the record that was read in into the correct number of items.  The `ItemProcessor<FullRecord, List<SmallRecords>` would return a list that you'd then loop through in a custom `ItemWriter` that wraps the `JdbcBatchItemWriter`.  Since the `ItemWriter` would receive a list of lists, you need to wrap the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` and loop through the parent list, passing each child list to the `JdbcBatchItemWriter`.

Comment: I've used the same approach before. Maybe a general `FlatteningItemWriter` that unwraps a list of lists and passes it to an `ItemWriter` delegate could be added to the framework?

Comment: As I was writing the response I was thinking the same thing.  A kind of a "JoinItemWriter" that joins expanded output from a processor...

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. It really helped me to find the solution